# XMLHttpRequest CORS request failing, even with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: nginx, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am having trouble making cross site ajax calls.  Using nginx, I believe I have added the right headers in the server configuration, but it still does not work in my JS code or in the console.  I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I type into the console the response is the familiar "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error:

```
$.get("//www.example.com");
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dictionary.aherriot.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I look at the response headers from my initial webpage load, I do see the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

and here is the nginx config file for the site:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/aherriot/sites/dictionary;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name dictionary.aherriot.com;

    location / {

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';

    }
}
```

I am stumped as to what I am missing.  What else do I need to do to allow CORS? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the question is there is a fundamental misunderstanding of what CORS is.  It is not for the origin server to specify which third-party domains  a page can access through XMLHttpRequest requests, but rather it is the server on an external domain that specifies which domains can connect to it.

Comment: I fixed my issue based on your response, but now I don't understand cors at all... I have a server with a React app and a server with static content, why would the server with the static content care about it if I can easily go to my browser and access the assets freely?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KHiSt0oLJ0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` to accept all origin but it will prevent using `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'`.

Take a look here for more examples - http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html